# Scrollable container without adding content

Tags: html, css, overflow

I created this snippet - https://codepen.io/Raven0us/pen/eYNGYYm, but I have to append content within it in order to work. A better solution would have been to just have an inner sample and increase the height of that on scroll, but none of them is what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to force a container to be scrollable without appending content to it? I thought having `max-height` set to `x` units, and increasing the height by double that would create a scrollable surface, but that doesn't seem to be the solution.

I'd like to know if it's possible when the entire markup consists of a sole element, like the following.

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: if i understood you correctly, you want an empty div to have a scrollbar and some empty space to scroll to ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Scrollbars are meant to allow the user access to content that is being hidden by overflow. in other words you have to cause overflow in order for scrollbars to appear, the easiest way i can think of is to use pseudo-classes https://jsfiddle.net/u3x4nrh2/

Answer (score 0):

Start with a DIV that is high enough to scroll on start up and then as the user scrolls use

```
document.getElementById("container").style.height += 10;
```

or something similar. So essentially as one scrolls they add 10 to the css style height.

Edit: In fact it shouldn't need to be scroll-able on start up.